# My app in Google Play doesn't offer to update itself

Tags: android, google-play

I'm having a strange issue with my app in Google Play. I'm not able to update it from its page in the market. I always get the "Open" button instead of the "Update" one after uploading a new build from the console

Let's say I have a build with version code 230 installed on my device. Now, following google's official [update guide](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en-GB), I generate a signed bundle with version code 238 (greater than the one in the market) and upload it through the console. After the new build is available I open my app's page in the Google Play app from my device. I expect to see the "Update" button under the rate section but I always get the "Open" one instead.

Am I missing something here? Is there anything I can do to overcome the issue? Or maybe my expectations are incorrect?

Comment: It takes a while (a couple of hours from my experience) for changes to propagate.

Comment: Uninstall and install again. and check did you get new features or something like that. Maybe you have tested app installed from Android studio which have same code version.

Comment: You are looking for the update using a phone with the public release downloaded from Google Play not testing device?

Comment: @SomerandomITboy it never takes the effect

Comment: @SahilGoyal I have build number (version code) printed inside the app. So I'm sure I have a version with the lower version code installed than the one in the market. I'm sure that the version in the market has been updated already because I always change the description

Comment: @SABANTO I have release version build on my device installed when trying to reproduce this issue. Do you mean that the app should be also signed in order for this to work? Side note is that if Google Play identified the installed app to be different from the one in the market I would get "Install" button instead of the "Open" one

Comment: @AlexKost that's strange as i never got problem regarding this.Mostly what i do is ,as soon as i release new version on play store ,i delete that app from my device and reinstall it from market.When i got notifications that my release is live, i just go to market where every time i got update option.